# DirectoryIterator::getExtension() version

Tags: php

I'm running a PHP script from CLI that user the `DirectoryIterator::getExtension()` method in PHP.

The version of PHP I'm running under is 5.3.5, but I keep getting errors saying `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DirectoryIterator::getExtension()`

The script works fine in my local dev machine running PHP 5.3.6, with no errors. However, the [page for DirectoryIterator::getExtension()](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getextension.php) in the PHP man has no mention of version.

Can anyone tell me what version I need to use this method?

Comment: The changelog (`NEWS`) says it was indeed introduced in 5.3.6. `Added SplFileInfo::getExtension(). FR #48767.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://php.net/manual/directoryiterator.getextension.php):

> (No version information available, might only be in SVN)

It seems like the commit didn't make the PHP 5.3.5 build, but got into the 5.3.6 release.  The page just hasn't been updated yet.

And as Mario pointed out, the [5.3.6 changelog](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.6) mentions the addition:

> - SPL extension:
>
>   - ...
>   - Added SplFileInfo::getExtension(). FR #48767. (Peter Cowburn)

Comment: thanks. I suppose I will have to use pathinfo() instead. Any other thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: @julio:  Other than updating your live version to something past 5.3.5, that seems like all you can do.

Answer (score 9):

This is a much simpler way to get the file extension, IMO:

```
<?php
  $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($data_dir);
  foreach($iterator as $entity) {
    if($entity->isFile()) {
      $file_extension = pathinfo($entity->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      ...
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

No wonder, I kept getting getExtension(). Although it is documented, it is not in verison 5.3.5. I'm using this workaround for the missing getExtension():

```
foreach($iter as $splFileInfo) {

  $fileName = $splFileInfo->getFilename();

  $pos_dot = strrpos($fileName, "."); // find '.'

  $ext = ($pos_dot !== false) ? substr($fileName, $pos_dot+1) : null;
  //. . .
}
```